# Combine multiple mysql data into one string and shown with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (img1) in mysql, and want to show the data at a php page which Col2 data will be combined if Col1 is same value (like the format of img2).

Question:

To handle the combining process, do it in sql query or in php is better? And how can I do so? Thank you.

 
[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
SELECT COl1, GROUP_CONCAT(COL2, SEPARATOR ' ') as COL2 FROM Table GROUP BY COl1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, group_concat(`Col1` separator ',') as `ColumnName`
from
(
  select id, concat(`Col1`, ':',
  group_concat(`Col2` separator ',')) as `Col1`
  from mytbl
  group by id, `Col1`
) tbl
group by id;
```

You can see it implemented here : [Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e51b7/11). Exactly what you need.